# Rendertron for NuxtJS and Firestore site for SEO purposes

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, seo, nuxtjs, rendertron

I would like to use [Rendertron](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/rendertron) for my NuxtJS site.

My nuxtjs firestore site is here at https://ampedcast.com and the rendertron site is here: https://render-tron.appspot.com/

According to this example given by google:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/dynamic-rendering#4

I need to add these few lines below to server.js in my nuxtjs site https://ampedcast.com but I could not figure out how to do that.  In nuxtjs, you are not supposed to make changes to server.js.

```
const rendertron = require('rendertron-middleware');

const BOTS = rendertron.botUserAgents.concat('googlebot');
const BOT_UA_PATTERN = new RegExp(BOTS.join('|'), 'i');

app.use(rendertron.makeMiddleware({
  proxyUrl: 'https://ampedcast-7c1d6.uc.r.appspot.com/render',
  userAgentPattern: BOT_UA_PATTERN
}));
```

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used NuxtJS myself but from the [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-server/) it says:

> Nuxt.js let you define the server connection variables for your application inside `nuxt.config.js`.

I am assuming you can configure your server settings there. You might also need a [Custom API endpoint](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-servermiddleware#custom-api-endpoint) and add this part to it:

```
app.use(rendertron.makeMiddleware({
  proxyUrl: 'https://ampedcast-7c1d6.uc.r.appspot.com/render',
  userAgentPattern: BOT_UA_PATTERN
}));
```

Then add the middleware to the `nuxt.config.js`:

```
serverMiddleware: [
  { path: "/api", handler: "~/api/rest.js" },
],
```

I have used other frameworks that do something similar. I would be interested to see if this works for you or if anyone else has a better answer to this.

Comment: I have added express and rendertron middleware to the app and you can see it from this test project that I have: https://github.com/somaria/nuxt-express/blob/main/api/index.js. The same configuration have been applied to the app in ampedcast.com, hope this is all that I need to do.